# How can NPM run a command that isn't in path

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, path, ava

The `ava` command is not in my path. I can not run it from in the project directory that contains some AVA tests.

My `npm test` command of my project is set to `ava tests/*.js --verbose`, and can somehow call the `ava` command from the same location in the terminal.

My questions is: how is npm calling the `ava` command? I suspect it is calling it from the project's `node_modules` folder, but I could not find it in any source.

If anyone can explain how this happens, or better yet show me the source, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run the `npm run [script]` or in this case `npm test`, NPM is smart enough to try to execute the binary from the `node_modules/.bin` directory first.

Comment: You say first, does that mean that there may not be an executable in `.bin` for some reason? Where would it look if it wasn't there?

Comment: I think it will then start looking into the packages you installed globally

Comment: Recent npm releases come with https://github.com/zkat/npx, so you can do `npx ava`.